# SQL: in CHECK, check varchar value in another table using entered foreign key

Tags: sql, pgadmin

One of the values to be inserted into a table is a foreign key. I need to figure out how to, inside the CHECK clause, check if a value in another table is equal to a specific value using the foreign key (which is unique in the other table).

[Example Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBFPr.png)

As an example, the MonkeySpecies table has a unique primary key. I need to make it so that the Monkey table can only be added to if the SpeciesID in the MonkeySpecies table is not 'extinct'.

Comment: If you have an FK defined why do you also want a check constraint? The FK will act as a check constraint anyway

Comment: I'm not checking if the foreign key is there, I'm checking if one of the elements of the tuple under that key in the other table is of a certain value. If not then you wouldn't be able to add the tuple to this table.

Comment: Ok , then please update your question with some sample data that illustrates what you are trying to achieve. What data would pass this check and what data would fail it?

Comment: Okay, I've edited my question.